# Populate drop down form SQL server using PHP and HTML

Tags: php

Whenever I try to run the below code, I get the passed variable ". $record . " as it is.
I am trying to populate a drop-down from a database, but I keep getting a value which I am passing in the while loop.. I know I am making a simple mistake.Can someone please help to solve this issue

```
        <select name="c" multiple="multiple">  
                    <option>--select--</option>
                    <?php
                    $dbname = "abc";
                    $serverName = "xyz"; //serverName\instanceName
                    try
                    {
                    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbname);
                    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
                    $SQL_string= "Select distinct [CC] from [abc].[dbo]. 
                                  [abcdefg] ";

                     $stmt =  sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL_string);
                     $records[] = array();
                       while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, 
                              SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                     {
                          $records[] = $row['CC'];

                      }   

                      foreach ($records as $record)
                      {
                        echo' <option value="'. $record . '">' .$record. 
                             '</option>';
                      }
                      if( $stmt === false ) {
                            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception $ex)
                    {
                       echo "Connection failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: You've got an open `try` block, a bunch of whitespace in the middle of your query, a case mismatch between "cc" and "CC", a missing space after `echo`, any of which might be a problem. But you haven't told us what your problem is. Can you show us what the relevant output of this looks like?

Comment: I get drop down box and in the box the text which I get is like this:                                     
                                CC:   ' .$record. '

Comment: No, look at your web browser, view source, and edit your question to show what is in the select element.

Comment: *"I get the passed variable ". $record . " as it is."* What does this mean? You are checking for errors in your SQL submission to the database AFTER processing the results of that query... that seems weird. You don't check for connection errors after making the connection to the database. Your try/catch won't necessarily catch that error since the connection attempt just returns `false` when the connection fails. I think this could be simplified, and in so doing, whatever the real issue is in this may become more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at simplifying this a bit. I can't guarantee it will work, but it may bring to light the error you are facing:

```
<select name="c" multiple="multiple">   
    <option>--select--</option>
    <?php
        $dbname = "abc";
        $serverName = "xyz"; //serverName\instanceName
        try
        {
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbname);
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
            if( $conn === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

            $SQL_string= "Select distinct [CC] from [abc].[dbo].[abcdefg];";

            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL_string);

            if( $stmt === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$row['CC'].'">'.$row['CC'].'</option>';
            } 

            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            echo "Caught exception error: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }


    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I found my mistake